# How to write plsql exception satatement to ask user to give input in specific format

Tags: exception, plsql, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_productdetails(

   p_reqid   OUT requirement.req_id%type,

   p_pid     OUT requirement.p_id%type,

   p_rstaffid OUT requirement.r_staff_id%type,
   
   p_demand  requirement.demand%type)

IS

CURSOR c_demand IS

SELECT req_id,p_id,r_staff_id from requirement where demand = upper(p_demand);

BEGIN

FOR i in c_demand Loop

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Requirement ID :'||i.req_id);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product ID'||i.p_id);

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Staff ID :'||i.r_staff_id);

END LOOP;

END get_productdetails;
```

*User must enter demand in 'HIGH/LOW/AVG only otherwise it should throw exception asking to enter data in that format
Can you please help me to write an exception accordingly*

Comment: There is no "EXCEPTION" block in your code - did you try it yourself ? What errors did you get ?

Comment: i got it from net i didn't write this code but how to add exception in this code can you help me with that

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you check documentation ? Stack Overflow is not a homework writing service. If you want people to help you, don't paste a block of code you found somewhere. Provide a working reproducible case: a ddl statement to create the table, the expected functionality and what you tried so far.

Comment: im learning on my own and trying to understand plsql procedures and functions i came across a Q where i was askedwrite a procedure Query and asked to inculde exceptions i tried to write the exception statment in the code but got an error while doing that it would be great if you can tell me how to add exception statment

Comment: 14/1     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "WHEN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         ( begin case declare end exit for goto if loop mod null
         pragma raise return select update while with <an identifier>
         <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> <a bind variable> <<
         continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
         savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
16/5     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "GET_PRODUCTDETAILS" when
         expecting one of the following:
         ;

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_productdetails(p_reqid   OUT requirement.req_id%type,p_pid     OUT requirement.p_id%type,p_rstaffid OUTrequirement.r_staff_id%type.p_demand  requirement.demand%type)
IS
CURSOR c_demand IS
SELECT req_id,p_id,r_staff_id from requirement where demand = upper(p_demand);
BEGIN 
FOR i in c_demand Loop

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product ID'||i.p_id);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Staff ID :'||i.r_staff_id);
WHEN OTHERS THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ENTER DEMAND IN UPPER CASE: );
END LOOP; 
END get_productdetails; //modified code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have access to your table structure, the code below is untested. A good place to start is the official [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-343E0653-9BCE-48F5-A00A-795D77B96B44). In your case, a user-defined exception is needed, which you need to declare in the declaration section, then `RAISE` and finally catch in the `EXCEPTION` block.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_productdetails(
   p_reqid   OUT requirement.req_id%type,
   p_pid     OUT requirement.p_id%type,
   p_rstaffid OUT requirement.r_staff_id%type,
   p_demand  requirement.demand%type)
IS
  -- declare the user-defined exception
  invalid_input EXCEPTION;
  CURSOR c_demand IS
  SELECT req_id,p_id,r_staff_id from requirement where demand = upper(p_demand);
BEGIN
  IF p_demand NOT IN ('HIGH','LOW','AVG') THEN
    -- raise the exception if p_demand not one of the 3 accepted values
    RAISE invalid_input;
  END IF;
  FOR i in c_demand Loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Requirement ID :'||i.req_id);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Product ID'||i.p_id);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Staff ID :'||i.r_staff_id);
  END LOOP;
EXCEPTION WHEN  invalid_input THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('Only HIGH/LOW/AVG are valid input');  
END get_productdetails;
```

Comment: Thank you Koen Lostrie for helping me understand how to use exception

Comment: Happy to help. Note that a trigger isn't optimal for validation of input. Usually this will be implemented on the "client" side